# Umbraco Examine Indexer exception when rebuilding index

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

When updating Umbraco to the latest version 7.4.3, we get a `Sqlexception` when Index rebuilds on app start. The message is: "Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding".

We have a db with extremely much content. The rebuild works if we set `supportUnpublished="false"`. Does anyone recognize this error?

Comment: I have seen this error message when we try to republish large websites with 1000s of nodes. this is mainly due to connection timeout between umbraco and sql server. Is your sql server live in the same sever as that IIS placed or in a different server? Checking your sql server timeout setting would be helpful.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution to this problem? I get exactly the same, and have "fixed" it by setting supportUnpublished="false"

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to add the 'ConnectionTimeout' property to your connection string. See the post below:

[Connection timeout for SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308417/connection-timeout-for-sql-server)

Goodluck

Craig

Comment: I have tried setting 'ConnectionTimeout' to wait unlimited amount of time but it still does not work.

Comment: You must have a lot of data! What about if you delete the indexes then restart your App and let Umbraco regenerate them on startup?