# Sql Select Query Timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Hello guys i am working on an query and every thing is working fine except when i run a query more than 2-3 times this return timeout is there is something wrong in my query or this is server error kindly suggest me here is my query

```
SELECT   
    Category_Feature_Mapping.Feature_ID,
    Category_Feature_Mapping.Category_ID, 
    Option_Table.Option_ID,  
    Option_Table.Title, 
    Feature_Table.Title AS featuretitle, 
    Feature_Table.Type
FROM 
    Category_Feature_Mapping 
    INNER JOIN Feature_Table 
        ON Category_Feature_Mapping.Feature_ID = Feature_Table.Feature_ID
    INNER JOIN Option_Table 
        ON Feature_Table.Feature_ID = Option_Table.Feature_ID 
WHERE 
    Category_Feature_Mapping.Category_ID = @catid
    AND Feature_Table.Feature_ID=@feid
    AND Feature_Table.Feature_ID not in (SELECT
                                             Feature_ID 
                                         FROM
                                             Vendor_Value_Table 
                                         WHERE
                                             Vendor_ID=@venid)                       
GROUP BY
    Category_Feature_Mapping.Feature_ID,
    Category_Feature_Mapping.Category_ID, 
    Option_Table.Option_ID, 
    Option_Table.Title, 
    Feature_Table.Title,
    Feature_Table.Type
```

Comment: How do you execute your query? SSMS? C#?

Comment: i m using c# to execute

Comment: The connection timeout default is 30 seconds. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308417/connection-timeout-for-sql-server

Comment: Look at the query plan and see what is holding it up.   You could be having lock problems.

Comment: @dudu markvoitz why should I increase timeout the query is returning not more than 50 items wo basically increasing timeout is bad habit I think kindly suggest something else.

Comment: @user1870546, can you add the number of rows in each table and the execution plan?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz dear as i say there are not more than 50 items

Comment: @user1870546, you are referring to the result set or to the base tables (which I'm interesting in)?

Comment: Maybe you have a parameter sniffing issue... Add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` at the end of the query. See [Query Hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx).

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz yes the query which is after not in clause that gives hardly 50 data rest the base table has more than 300-400 data but i don't think so my db size is more it will increase in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to append ";Connection Timeout=100" to you connectionstring for up your timeout

Comment: but don't you think its bad habit to increase connection timeout while there are not more than 50 data?

Comment: may be one table is loked sometime, try wrkobjlck if you are on iseries

Comment: i think table is locked during updation here i am just selecting data set

Answer (score 0):

may by a question of performance, try to replace "not in" by "not exists" like this

```
 AND not exists (
 SELECT * FROM Vendor_Value_Table vvt
 WHERE Feature_Table.Feature_ID =vvt.Feature_ID and vvt.Vendor_ID=@venid
 )
```

Comment: The problem exist after this amendment

Comment: your tables are indexed on id?

Comment: Can you put your connectionstring