# c# - Tableadapter not working because of timeout

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timeout, tableadapter

My `TableAdapter` is defined in an ADO.NET data set. My stored procedure is executed in 50 seconds in SSMS. When I'm trying to execute it in application I get timeout.

How to set timeout connection value for `TableAdapter`?

Answer (score 3):

There are two places where we can set timeouts.

1. `SqlConnection`
2. `SqlCommand`

`SqlConnection` has **`ConnectionTimeout`** property. It specifies the time ADO.Net waits for when trying to connect to the server. If no connection is made to the Server (network down/server not running etc), an exception is thrown.

`SqlCommand` has **`CommandTimeout`** property. It specifies the wait time for the results to come back once the command is executed (you call `Execute`/`ExecuteNoQuery` etc). If no results are returned in specified time, it throws an exception. By default, the command timeout is 30 seconds. So, if the command is taking 50 seconds, you will get an exception.

For `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` it is simple, simply set the value of the property on the objects.

For the `TableAdapter`, you have two ways to set `ConnectionTimeout` (both lead to same output). First is to set in the connection string. Second is setting it in the `Advanced` properties dialogue when you setup connection for the adapter.

For `CommandTimeout`, you need to access the specific command from the adapter which is timing out. If the select command is blowing up, you can use this:

```
var ta = new YouTableAdapter();
ta.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 100;
```

Comment: I set connection timeout in the connection string. It worked. But today I got "timeout connection" after 30 seconds like before. I don't know how can I solve this..

Comment: Have you tried setting `Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout`? Can you check what timeout is it giving for `Connection` for `SelectCommand`?
It can be any reason, but have you thought about paging your data to load it faster? Or setting up some indices on the server?

Comment: As I understand you cannot set CommandTimeout for typed TableAdapter because there is no public property exposed. I've extended partial TableAdapter class and set CommandTimeout value. Then I called this property from the windows form class using this TableAdapter.

Comment: Well, I don't use `TableAdapter` in my code. I had added a data source and copied the lines from `VS`. So it means that it give you the different commands to set properties. **NOTE** You cannot set **`CommandTimeout`** on `TableAdapter` itself. You have to pick a command like `Select`, `Update` etc and set timeout on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the time-out on the connection string and not the table adapter:

[Connection timeout for SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308417/connection-timeout-for-sql-server)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. It did the job.

Comment: Yesterday it worked. Today I got timeout like before- after 30 sec.

Comment: you can increase it from 30 seconds upwards not realy advisable if data is taking so long could be a relationship issue in the underlying data or just found a weird behaviour when debugging an issue IIS express caps out at 3GB ram memory usage :(  Try changing it up and look at your table indexing.