# SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) : Is there a way to specify connection.StatementTimeout using a config file?

Tags: sql-server, smo

One of the applications using SMO  that is running in production is giving a timeout error on a long running query. I have access to code and can set the Connection.StatementTimeOut to 0 or a high enough value. But is there a .config or any configuration file associated with SMO wherein I can specify this property ? The thought is update or deploy this file in the production environment instead of deploying code.

Comment: see this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308417/connection-timeout-for-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection timeout for SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308417/connection-timeout-for-sql-server)