# Default Timeout Period in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I got the error

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

during the command execution.

I also set `Connect Timeout=60` in the connection string.

That stored procedure execution time is around 35 seconds.

Connection is established, but result is not returned.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847264/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlcommand-commandtimeout-and-sqlconnection-conne

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between SqlCommand.CommandTimeout and SqlConnection.ConnectionTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847264/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlcommand-commandtimeout-and-sqlconnection-conne)

Comment: Have you thought whether it is possible to optimise your stored procedure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DbCommand` has `CommandTimeout`, which is what you want here - it is set per command; the "connect timeout" only impacts, reasonably enough, what the timeout is *for connecting*. The default value for `CommandTimeout` on `SqlCommand` is 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can also extend connection timeout in connectionstring

> ;Connection Timeout=30

See: [Connection timeout for SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308417/connection-timeout-for-sql-server)

Comment: that is the timeout for *connecting*, not for *executing*. You cannot set the execution timeout in the connectionstring